# Running ubuntu in virtualbox, low screen resolution/dimensions

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, resolution

I am running windows 7 natively, i7 64 bit chipset.

ATI radeon hd 4800 series video card.

I have virtual box.

For some reason, when running ubuntu in virtualbox, the screen rez is like 600x480 (very very small).

Is this because ubuntu can't figure out my video card?

Comment: What is ubuntu reporting as the vid card?

Comment: No. It's because VirtualBox creates a virtual video card and you need to install the driver for that.  See solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install the virtualbox-ose-guest-x11 package

Comment: I run `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-x11` and it complains that it is unable to locate the package.

Answer (score 0):

For those who tried to solve the issue by installed this package with no luck, try removing it first, then insert VBoxGuestAdditions.iso image (under Program Files directory of VirtualBox) into your virtual machine, and then run VBoxLinuxAdditions.run file under your guest operating system.